# Adding a starter for gnome-control-center in docky

Tags: 10.04, gnome, gui, docky

I want to add a starter for the *gnome-control-center in Docky* (This is possible in Linux Mint by default. The gnome-control-center behaves like an app.)

However, I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.3 & Docky v2.2.0. I can only open the gnome-control-center via terminal.

Is there a GUI I can install? I have not found anything using Synaptics and Software Center.

[image]

Comment: Start gnome-settings-manager via the terminal - this will appear as an icon in Docky.  Right click the icon and pin it to docky.  Am I missing some understanding in your question?

Comment: Thing is that this is not possible for me in docky. All the options that I have available are:
-maximize
-minimize
-close

Comment: please can you add a link into your question to a screenshot showing gnome-settings-manager running together with the "options maximize minimize" etc.  I'm not sure I understand what you are visually seeing on the screen.  Also, please add to your question the version of ubuntu and the version of docky.

Comment: Ups... I made a mistake. I've been talking about gnome-control-center all the time.

Comment: I cannot add a screen shot of the available options. It will not work.... however I'll add a screen shot off the gnome control center when opened.

Comment: Screenshot: http://cl.ly/9lYl              Ubuntu 10.04.3
           Docky 2.2.0     Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 1):

The version you have indicated for Docky probably has come from the [Docky Developers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~docky-core/+archive/ppa).

As the developers them-selves say - this is unstable - and what you have found is a bug.  You should file this as a bug-report on Launchpad.

My recommendation is that either you should stay with the version of Docky available in the repositories - or if you are looking for something newer but "stable", then look at installing from the [Docky-Stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~docky-core/+archive/stable)

You will need `ppa-purge`  which is available if you tick the "Ubuntu Backports" in Software Sources.  You can the purge the development docky PPA

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:docky-core/ppa
```

Then install the stable PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can pin `gnome-control-center`

[image]